# Adding seconds to Jquery timepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, timepicker

I have a jQuery Timepicker code below:

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        button: '.timepicker_button_trigger'
});
```

This Timepicker can be seen on this website: [here](http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/)

The problem which I can't find the solution of is that I want to include seconds in this Timepicker with hours and minutes. Is there a solution for this with this Timepicker or not?

I am using the timepicker to set the duration of something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check this: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ and see if helps you

there you have some examples working with seconds.

example:

```
$('#example5').datetimepicker({
   showSecond: true,
   showMillisec: true,
   timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss:l'
});
```